# Connection between the BT instruction and the carry flag CF

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag

I know that for example `BT BX, 0` transfers the first bit of the `BX` register to the carry flag CF.

Isn't the carry flag restricted to only have values of 0 and 1, because it's a flag?

Does `BT` change the CF value from the first bit of the register even if it doesn't hold 0 or 1?

If someone would be able to write here how it works, it would be great!

Comment: "the first bit of the register even if it doesn't hold 0 or 1?" A bit by definition holds a 0 or a 1. More doesn't fit into a **bi**nary dig**it** (bit). Like a decimal digit is always 0 to 9 and no more, a binary digit is 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Carry flag can have one of only two possible values: **0** or **1**.
So does any bit of any register, for instance the least significant bit Nr.0 of `BX`.
Its value is copied by `BT BX,0` to CF; BTW this can be used to test if the number in `BX` is odd or even:

```
    BT BX,0
    JC Odd
Even:
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that the BT command is like an if statement:
If the first bit in bx is set, so the carryflag will present the answer - true = 1?
and what does it mean if a bit is set?

Comment: `BT BX,0` is like `IF (the 0-th bit in BX is set) THEN (set CF to 1) ELSE (reset CF to 0)`. What does setting CF mean is up to you: you can branch the thread with `JC` or `JNC`, you can add its value to another register with `ADC reg,0`, you can contitionaly copy one register to another with `CMOVC AX,BX` etc.

Comment: Great! thanks! and can I add a Jump command after BT like I do on cmp?

Comment: Sure you can add a conditional jump after `BT`, that's the purpose of testing bits in register with `BT`.

Comment: @עילאירצ'קובסקי: Branching isn't the only purpose.  You can `sbb eax, eax` to create a 0 or -1 or `setc al` to create a 0 or 1.  Or you can `adc al, 0` to add CF to another register.  You can even `adc al, '0'` to create an ASCII '0' / '1' base-2 digit, if the register was initially 0.  Or with 686 as well as 386 (for BT) features, you can `cmovc ecx, edx` to do `if(CF) ecx = edx` branchlessly.  Or you can `adc edx,edx` to shift CF into the bottom of EDX.  (Or `rcr edx, 1` to right-shift it into the top).  CF has lots of special things you can do with it. But yes you *can* `jc` or `jnc` on it.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no single instruction that does the opposite of BT, copying CF into a given position in a register.  BT / BTS / BTR / BTC only write CF, not read it.

Comment: @עילאירצ'קובסקי: Normally for test odd / even, you'd `test al, 1` / `jnz odd`, so BT is most useful for other bit-positions.  Or if you need the result in CF for something other than branching.  Of course, if you want a 0 or 1 integer, you use `and eax, 1` if it's just the low bit-position you want to isolate, not round-tripping through FLAGS.

Answer (score 4):

[BT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BT.html) is the instruction to test if a bit is set(`1`) or not(`0`). Hence it can only return two values, one or zero, which fit into a (E)FLAG value that can be either TRUE(`1`) or FALSE(`0`).

So `BT` directly copies this bit into the CarryFlag.
The position of the desired bit is given with the immediate value at the end of the instruction - here it is `0`, meaning the lowest bit in `BX`.

(`BT` does not change the bit tested. For that purpose, you should use [BTC](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BTC.html), [BTR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BTR.html) and [BTS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BTS.html).)

Comment: So what you are saying is that the BT command is like an if statement:
If the first bit in bx is set, so the carryflag will present the answer - true = 1?
and what does it mean if a bit is set?

Comment: It's not even as complicated as an IF-THEN-ELSE. As I wrote, it just *copies* the 0/1 from the register (from the given bit position) to the (E)FLAGs register. By convention, `0`=`FALSE`=`NOT SET` and `1`=`TRUE`=`SET`.